# How do I exit a runBlocking coroutine from another class (in Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, exit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to make my code exit the program when something happens, such as a user exit command.
This is how I'm running my program:

```kotlin
fun main() = runBlocking {
    Bot().start()
}
```

Unfortunately, running `exitProcess(0)` or `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` doesn't seem to do anything when called outside of `start()`, which is really inconvient in my use case.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: What does `start()` look like?

Comment: https://github.com/kami-blue/bot-kt/blob/8013620ba3bfd97fda7138c7fe5392b98d8bd9c3/src/main/kotlin/Main.kt#L25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```kotlin
runBlocking {
    val job = launch { start() }
    // Process input via other APIs here. When done:
    job.cancel()
}
```

(You may want to look into [channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html#channels) to deliver `Cmd` objects into your command loop, and just close the channel when input is done.)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. 

I have [this](https://pastebin.com/raw/2qCCFwnE)

Comment: cancel() will cause the next suspension point in start() to throw CancellationException. If start() is already complete or stuck in blocking IO then cancel() won't do anything.

Comment: `start()` doesn't have any suspension points, it finishes as it's a start sequence. Would using a `delay(largeNumber)` or some infinite while loop be able to work around this?

Comment: I needed to call `exitProcess(0)` after cancelling the job from another process, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a same issue with `runBlocking`.

***A little background:***  First of all, We had to use `runBlocking` in order to bridge the gap between an interface implementation of a library method and our app's component that can only be accessed on the MAIN/UI thread. Inside the implementation of this method we had to synchronously return a value, we had to switch our context from Background thread to UI thread to explicitly fetch this information on the UI thread. It was never our choice to use `runBlocking` but we had to as there was no other way.

***The Problem:*** This `runBlocking` was blocking the other background thread (in a certain situation). It was never ending and it blocked the background thread which was running in a separate child process of our application. So I looked up for a solution and found below reported issue on Github.

According to an answer in a reported issue [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/501)

> When `runBlocking` machinery detects that it is cancelled it should
> not terminate its event loop **until the coroutine inside it is still**
> **active**.

Then he further explains that

> This way, the termination of the coroutine is processed in the running
> event loop and the event loop terminates after that.

***The Solution:*** So I came up with this solution that worked for me mentioned below, you can use this higher-order function. This is a 100% working solution, tested & verified in production. *NOTE: Please don't use `withContext()` instead of `async()` in the code snippet below as it will never work.*

```
fun <T> runBlockingWithTimeout(
    lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope?,
    timeoutMillis: Long = 500L,
    block: () -> T
): T? {
    return lifecycleScope?.let {
        runBlocking {
            withTimeoutOrNull(timeMillis = timeoutMillis) {
                async(lifecycleScope.coroutineContext) {
                    block.invoke()
                }.await()
            }
        }
    }
}
```